# Figure size with 0 Axes, using jupiter, seaborn catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter

I use seaborn to plot violin histgram. When I used `plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 80)` to change figsize, the jupiter outputs `Figure size  with 0 Axes` and the original violin figure.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 80)
sns.catplot(x=" ", y=" ", hue=" ", kind="violin", split=True,  data=data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`sns.catplot` has two parameter, "height and aspet", to change figure size of this seaborn figure. `plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 80)` would just create an empty figure and could not change figure size.

The meaning of "height and aspet" is below:

```
height    scalar
Height (in inches) of each facet. 

aspect    scalar
Aspect ratio of each facet, so that aspect * height gives the width of each facet in inches.
```

for your code you can change it to below

```
sns.catplot(x=" ", y=" ", hue=" ", kind="violin", split=True, height=8, aspect=1.5,  data=data)
plt.show()
```